# Assembly tasm error relative jump out of range

Tags: assembly, tasm

I am very new to Assembly and I am trying to program the task, which requires to divide input up to 80 characters and modify it every 24 bits (3 blocks of 8 bits) by substiting bits in the following order 5 -> 15 -> 20 -> 1-> 6 (5th bit goes to the place of 15 bit, 15 bit goes to the place of 20 bit and so on). However, I get an relative jump out of range error when calling loop after subsituting final bit 5->15. Could somebody please advise what's wrong in this code? I would very appreciate some help here. Thanks in advance.

```
.model small
   ASSUME CS:kodas, DS:duomenys, SS:stekas
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
stekas segment word stack 'STACK'
   dw 400h dup (00)               ; stekas -> 2 Kb
stekas ends
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
duomenys segment para public 'DATA'

pranesimas1:
   db 'Enter row up to 80 symbols'
naujaEilute:   
   db 0Dh, 0Ah, '$'  ; tekstas ant ekrano
pranesimas2:
   db 'Entered symbols are grouped every 24 bits: ', 0Dh, 0Ah, '$'  
pranesimas3:
   db '24 bitu bloko bitai sukeiciami pagal schema: 5 -> 15 -> 20 -> 1-> 6: ', 0Dh, 0Ah, '$'
pranesimas4:
   db 'Amount of zero bits is:', 0Dh, 0Ah, '$'
buferisIvedimui:
   db 81, 00, 83 dup (0)  
a:
   db 00
b:
   db 00
c:
   db 00
bit0:
   dw 0000
bit1:
   dw 0000
buferisAtsakymui:
   sk1  db  00
   sk2  db  00      
   sk3  db  00
        db  0Dh, 0Ah,'$'  
duomenys ends

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

LOCALS  @@

kodas segment para public 'CODE'
spausdinkBaitoDvKoda proc near

   push        dx
   push        ax
   push        cx
   push        bx 

   mov         cx, 0008
   mov dh,     al                                   
   mov bl,     10000000b                            

   @@ciklas_pagal_cx_nuo_8:
   mov dl,     dh
   and dl,     bl                                  
   dec cl                                          
   shr dl,     cl                                   
   shr bl,     1                                    
   inc cl                                           
   add dl,     '0'                                 
   mov ah,     02                                   
   int 21h                                          
   loop  @@ciklas_pagal_cx_nuo_8                    


   pop bx
   pop cx
   pop ax
   pop dx                
   ret
spausdinkBaitoDvKoda endp
;--------------------------------------------------------    
spausdinkTarpa proc near

   push        dx
   push        ax
   mov dl,     ' '                               
   mov ah,     02                                 
   int 21h
   pop ax
   pop dx                
   ret
spausdinkTarpa endp
;-------------------------------------------------------
skaiciuokBituSk proc near

   push        dx
   push        ax
   push        cx
   push        bx 

   mov         cx, 0008
   mov dh,     al                                  
   mov bl,     10000000b                            

   @@ciklas_pagal_cx_8:
   mov dl,     dh
   and dl,     bl                                   
   dec cl                                          
   shr dl,     cl                                  
   shr bl,     1                                    
   inc cl                                          
   xor ax,     ax                                   
   mov al,     dl                                      
   add word ptr bit0, ax
   loop  @@ciklas_pagal_cx_8                        

   mov cl,     byte ptr[buferisIvedimui + 1]        
   mov al,     cl                                  
   mov bl,     8                                    
   mul bl                                           
   sub ax, word ptr bit0                            
   mov word ptr bit1, ax                            


   pop bx
   pop cx
   pop ax
   pop dx                
   ret
skaiciuokBituSk endp
;-------------------------------------------------------
pradzia:

   mov ax,     seg duomenys                 
   mov ds,     ax

   mov ah,     09                           
   mov dx,     offset pranesimas1             
   int 21h

   mov ah,     0Ah                            
   mov dx,     offset buferisIvedimui         
   int 21h       

   mov ah,     09                            
   mov dx,     offset naujaEilute             
   int 21h


   mov ah,     09                             
   mov dx,     offset naujaEilute               
   int 21h

   mov ah,     09                            
   mov dx,     offset pranesimas2             
   int 21h

   xor cx,     cx                              
   mov cl,     byte ptr[buferisIvedimui + 1]   
   xor ax,     ax                              
   mov al,     cl                              
   mov bl,     byte ptr 3                      
   div bl                                      
   mov cl,     al                              
   xor bx,     bx                              
   mov bx,     2                               

   @@ciklas1_pagal_cx_nuo_baitu_skaiciaus:     


   mov al,     byte ptr[buferisIvedimui + bx + 2]  
   mov byte ptr c, al                             
   call SpausdinkBaitoDvKoda                       
   call spausdinkTarpa 
   mov al,     byte ptr[buferisIvedimui + bx + 1]  
   mov byte ptr b, al
   call SpausdinkBaitoDvKoda                       
   call spausdinkTarpa 
   mov al,     byte ptr[buferisIvedimui + bx]      
   mov byte ptr a, al                              
   call SpausdinkBaitoDvKoda                       
   call spausdinkTarpa                             

   ; 5 -> 15 -> 20 -> 1-> 6


   ;1->6
   mov ah,     byte ptr a                          
   and ah,     00000010b                           
   and byte ptr a,     10111101b                    
   shl ah,     1                                    
   shl ah,     1                                    
   shl ah,     1                                    
   shl ah,     1                                    
   shl ah,     1
   or  byte ptr a,     ah 

   ;20->1
   mov dl, byte ptr c
   and dl,     00010000b
   and byte ptr c,     11101111b
   shr dl,     1
   shr dl,     1
   shr dl,     1       
   or  byte ptr a,     dl

   ;15->20
   mov ah, byte ptr b
   and ah,     10000000b
   and byte ptr b,     01111111b
   shr ah,     1
   shr ah,     1
   shr ah,     1
   or  byte ptr c,     ah 

   ;5->15

   mov ah, byte ptr a
   and ah,     00100000b
   and byte ptr a,     11011111b
   shl ah,     1
   shl ah,     1
   or  byte ptr b,     ah 


   mov al, byte ptr a
   mov byte ptr[buferisIvedimui + bx], al 

   mov al, byte ptr b
   mov byte ptr[buferisIvedimui + bx + 1], al 

   mov al, byte ptr c
   mov byte ptr[buferisIvedimui + bx + 2], al 

   inc bx                                          
   add bx,     2

   loop @@ciklas1_pagal_cx_nuo_baitu_skaiciaus   

   mov ah,     09                                
   mov dx,     offset naujaEilute               
   int 21h


   mov ah,     09                                
   mov dx,     offset naujaEilute               
   int 21h

   mov ah,     09                            
   mov dx,     offset pranesimas3            
   int 21h

   xor cx,     cx                              
   mov cl,     byte ptr[buferisIvedimui + 1]   
   xor ax,     ax                              
   mov al,     cl                              
   mov bl,     byte ptr 3                     
   div bl                                      
   mov cl,     al                             
   xor bx,     bx                              
   mov bx,     2                               

   @@ciklas2_pagal_cx_nuo_baitu_skaiciaus:


   mov al,     byte ptr[buferisIvedimui + bx + 2]  
   call SpausdinkBaitoDvKoda                      
   call spausdinkTarpa 
   mov al,     byte ptr[buferisIvedimui + bx + 1]  
   call SpausdinkBaitoDvKoda                      
   call spausdinkTarpa 
   mov al,     byte ptr[buferisIvedimui + bx]      
   call SpausdinkBaitoDvKoda                      
   call spausdinkTarpa                            

   inc bx                                          
   add bx,     2

   loop @@ciklas2_pagal_cx_nuo_baitu_skaiciaus

   ;Calculating total amount of null bits
   xor cx,     cx                                  
   mov cl,     byte ptr[buferisIvedimui + 1]       
   mov bx,     2                                   

   @@ciklas1_pagal_cx_nuo_baitu_skaiciaus1:        

   mov al,     byte ptr[buferisIvedimui + bx]      
   call skaiciuokBituSk                            

   inc bx                                          

   loop @@ciklas1_pagal_cx_nuo_baitu_skaiciaus1   

   mov ax, word ptr bit1                          

   mov dx,     0000
   mov bx,     word ptr 10
   div bx                                          


   add dl, '0'       
   mov byte ptr sk3,  dl


   mov dx,     0000
   div bx


   add dl, '0'       
   mov byte ptr sk2,  dl


   mov dx,     0000
   div bx


   add dl, '0'       
   mov byte ptr sk1,  dl

   mov ah,     09                                
   mov dx,     offset naujaEilute               
   int 21h

   mov ah,     09                               
   mov dx,     offset naujaEilute              
   int 21h

   mov ah,     09                            
   mov dx,     offset pranesimas4          
   int 21h

   mov dx,     offset buferisAtsakymui
   mov ah,     09
   int 21h


   mov ah,     4ch                            
   int 21h

   mov ah, '?'
kodas  ends
end pradzia
```

Comment: And what does `mov bl, byte ptr 3` do?  Is that a `mov r, imm8`, or a load from an absolute address of `3`?  Instead of zeroing ax and them `mov al, cl`, you could just do `movzx  ax, cl` to zero-extend an 8bit src into a 16bit dest.  (That's another 386 feature, like the larger-displacement jcc encodings.)

Answer (score 1):

`loop @@ciklas1_pagal_cx_nuo_baitu_skaiciaus` causes the error. `LOOP` can only perform short jumps (–128 to +127 bytes). In this case you **cannot** replace it by

```
dec cx
jne @@ciklas1_pagal_cx_nuo_baitu_skaiciaus
```

(see https://stackoverflow.com/a/32769524/3512216), because the jump is yet too wide for a conditional jump (`jne`). For a remedy look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/32626759/3512216.

You can let TASM do the transformation. Just place a line with `JUMPS` to the beginning of the text. TASM transforms the invalid loop to (label names added by me):

```
loop LOOP
jmp ENDLOOP
LOOP:
jmp @@ciklas1_pagal_cx_nuo_baitu_skaiciaus
ENDLOOP:
```

Comment: @Martin: At some point after 8086 (maybe 386, maybe earlier), 16 or 32bit-displacement versions of the `jcc` instructions were added.  You're only stuck with this ugly workaround if you're actually targeting an ancient ISA, like an 8086 microcontroller.  Otherwise just tell your assembler it can use the conditional near jump encoding.  Since you're using DOS `int 21h` calls, I assume you're going to run this on a normal computer.